# Bash to rerun a program for each config file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create config files on deployment, and then run my program for each config file, loading the configuration into environmental variables each time. This is the closest I can do:

```
# ADD CONFIG
mkdir /cfg
cat > /cfg/site.cfg << EOF
name = site         
url = ftp.site.com    # Location of data 
username = test          # Optional - Username credential
password = pass          # Optional - Password credential 
frequency = 1            # Optional - Update once a day
EOF

# ADD SCRIPT
cat > /run.sh << EOF
for f in cfg
do
    echo "Processing $f"
        #set env from config
        #run program with env
done
```

How do I set the env vars using my config prior to running the program (so it can be run with that specific set of requirements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can be something like this

```
cat > /run.sh << EOF
for f in cfg
do
    echo "Processing $f"
        #set env from config
        #run program with env
    bash -c "set -a; source $f; ./exec_prog"
done
```

All variable set in $f will be available for exec_prog.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Can I ask why you use the bash -c command instead of just running the command inside the quotes?

Comment: if you dont run with bash -c then all your config files will be sourced in your current shell i.e at the end of loop, variables in all config files will be part of your current shell. So your current shells environment is disturbed. bash -c executes command in new shell so your current shell is not effected.

Answer (score 1):

You can source your cfg file before you being the execution of the main script.

```
CFGFILE=<Your Corresponding Config File>


# ADD SCRIPT
cat > /run.sh << EOF
CFGFILE=$1
if [ ! -f "$CFGFILE" ] 
then
    echo "Error: Unable to source file $CFGFILE" >&2
    exit 1
fi

. $CFGFILE

    echo "Processing $f"
    #set env from config
    #run program with env
```